# Limit of Taylor Coefficients Near a Simple Pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I am practicing for an analysis qual and came across this question:

> Suppose $f$ is analytic on $|z| < R$ except for a simple pole at $z_0$, $0 <
> \> |z_0| < R$. If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is the Taylor series
> for $f$ near the origin, show that  $$ A = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n
> \> z_0^{n+1} $$ exists and is not zero.

I am stumped on how to start this and would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Maybe you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n
\> z_0^{n+1}$?

Comment: How do you recognize that $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin We can write $f = \frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}$ near $z_0$ for some analytic $g$, where $g(z_0) \neq 0$. Equivalently, there is a Laurent expansion in some annulus around $z_0$ with a non-zero $a_{-1}$ term.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2104380/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I just used this fact today in a research meeting!)

Hint: if $r$ is the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=z_0$, consider the Maclaurin series coefficients of $g(z) = f(z) - r/(z-z_0)$.

Comment: Thank you! How I understand it is that this $g(z)$ must be entire, so the Maclaurin series converges at $z_0$. But then the limit of the terms must go to zero. Working out the algebra, we get that $\lim_{n \to \infty} = -r$.

Comment: Not entire, no. Are you sure about that sign?

Comment: Ah, I suppose it has a removable discontinuity at $z_0$ still. But we still get that $g$ has a limit at $z_0$ and could be extended to be analytic there. Hmm, I'll look at my workings to see if I missed a minus sign anywhere.

Comment: I think the problem with "entire" isn't about the removable discontinuity (we're used to filling those in), but with the fact that $f$ is only defined on $\{|z|<R\}$ rather than the entire complex plane.